# How to switch between ImageMapType and StyledMapType

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In google map v3, I want to switch between ImageMapType and StyledMapType at different zoom levels. But I got error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Here is test code:

```
    var curLabLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(36.415793, -121.084421);

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 21,
      streetViewControl: false,
      center: curLabLocation,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP
    };
    var $map = $('#map-canvas');
    myMap = new google.maps.Map($map[0], mapOptions);

    var zoom2_MapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({

      getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        // No image
        return null;
      },
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),

      maxZoom: 24,
      minZoom: 22,
      name: 'zoom2'
    });

    var mapStyleNormalZoom = [{featureType: "landscape", 
                              elementType: "all", 
                              stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
                             }];

    var zoom1_StyledMapOptions = {map: myMap, name: 'zoom1'}; 
    var zoom1_MapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyleNormalZoom,
                                                      zoom1_StyledMapOptions); 


    myMap.mapTypes.set('zoom2', zoom2_MapType);
    myMap.mapTypes.set('zoom1', zoom1_MapType);  

    // The following 2 lines tries to simulate switching between 2 map types. But it does not work in 2nd case.
    // NO problem to switch from "zoom1" to "zoom2".
    //myMap.setMapTypeId('zoom1');
    //myMap.setMapTypeId('zoom2');

    // Switch from "zoom2" to "zoom1" cause exception error.
    // ERROR: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    myMap.setMapTypeId('zoom2');
    myMap.setMapTypeId('zoom1'); //This line causes "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
```

I am not sure if this is right way to switch.

Question: Is this right way to switch between  ImageMapType and StyledMapType? How to do it?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: curLabLocation is not defined`, if I define that, I don't see the reported error.

Comment: My code is pseudo code. You should not simply copy and run it. I correct it anyway. You did not solve my problem.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I added missing var curLabLocation. You should not having 'Uncaught ReferenceError: curLabLocation is not defined'.

Comment: Do you use "debug" to check that code could execute `myMap.setMapTypeId('zoom2');` ?

Comment: Yes, in Chrome, I got error message "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" at line myMap.setMapTypeId('zoom1');

Comment: I had change `myMap = new google.maps.Map($map[0], mapOptions);` into `myMap = new google.maps.Map($map, mapOptions);`
what's your `$('#map-canvas');` code??

I had check on jsfiddle and `myMap.setMapTypeId('zoom1');` could be executed and not got error message.

Comment: $('#map-canvas') is a div to hold map in html. Can you post your jsfiddle? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that switching between 2 types are correct? Is this way to switch? I could not find any sample. As far as I know if you have multiple StyledMapType defined, you can switch them with setMapTypeId(). But, I am not sure if switching between StyledMapType and ImageMapType